# Use if statement and return value to c# from a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

All I want to do is check if a name exists in a given table in my database or not but I am getting multiple returns from the stored procedure causing an exception.

This is the stored procedure I am using in SQL Server:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ContactExists 
    @Name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @result bit = 0
    DECLARE @name varchar(50) = '';

    SET @name = (SELECT Name FROM Table)

    IF (@name = @Name)
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 1
        RETURN @result
    END

    RETURN @result
END
GO
```

And this is the method I am using in C#:

```
SPstr = "dbo.ContactExists";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SPstr, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);

var returnValue = cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

return (int)returnValue.Value;
```

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: The SP query is wrong and the implementation could be changed. Try working on the SP first and verify it's working and then work on the implementation in C#.

Comment: *`set @name = (SELECT Name from Table)`* - what are you expecting SQLServer to do with this? If there are 1000 rows in the table, how should it stuff them all into a  single variable that holds one string? Also, I'm somewhat on the fence as to whether this is a valid use of a return value from a sproc; theyre intended to indicate state of the operation, not data - while this isn't data in the sense of "the count of the names in the table", it doesn't seem like operational state in this fragment either

Comment: Don't use the stored procedure return code for this purpose; it's intended to be used for to indicate success (zero) or error/warning (nonzero). Use an output parameter or result set instead.

Comment: Also, how did you get this to compile `@Name varchar(50) ... declare @name varchar(50)` - variable names aren't case sensitive, so that should throw an "already declared" error

Comment: What is your intentions after running this when it's working? Insert a new contact etc? Anyways, you probably could refactor this (or another SP) depending on use case...

Comment: return values are integers, don't use a bit.  Also, have you checked cmd.Parameters("@result").value?

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @SMor yeah, but it's a SProc; bigger fish to fry atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the return value from stored procedures to return data.  It's an old and mostly obsolete way to signal success or failure of the proc.  So either use an output parameter:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ContactExists 
    @Name varchar(50), @result bit output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    set @result = 0;
    
    if exists (SELECT * FROM SomeTable where name = @Name)
    begin
      set @result = 1;
    end


END
```

or a resultset

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ContactExists 
    @Name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @result bit = 0;
    
    if exists (SELECT * FROM SomeTable where name = @Name)
    begin
      set @result = 1;
    end

    select @result result;
END
```

Comment: I am new to SQL so I don't really know about all the statements but the "if exists" you suggested helped so thank you.
Even if return value is old and obsolete, because I have just started learning about SQL I will try to slowly phase it out.

Answer (score 3):

> I am getting multiple returns from the stored procedure causing an exception.

I suspect you mean you're getting this:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

which is going to arise from this:

```
set @name = (SELECT Name from Table)
```

if `Table` has more than one row. Ensure the subquery (`SELECT Name from Table`) returns at most one row (use a WHERE on the pk, use MAX etc..)

Comment: Yes you are right, this is my very first question here so in order to make it concise I forgot about mentioning the exception.
I will remember to include it properly in future question.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, click the gray check mark to the left of the answer, turn it green. This changes the appearance of the question on the dashboard to let people know you're not still looking for an answer. You can also click the up arrow on any number of answers you found useful, including this one.